# Are there specific IIS setting recommendations for Sitecore?

Tags: configuration, iis

Are there any specific setting changes for IIS specific to Sitecore? Or are general ASP.NET IIS best practices fully applicable to Sitecore?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is entirely appropriate as it is pretty open ended. However, I had a client come to me recently to ask me "to make sure all of the IIS settings are correct" - and I'm not aware of any Sitecore specific changes. I'd love some feedback.

Comment: Please be more specific on question. do you mean IIS modules for Sitecore? Sitecore configuration files? etc

Comment: Not necessarily modules. I am looking for configuration - whether that is in the web.config or something accomplished through the IIS GUI. See Sitecore Climber's answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I will recommend these specific settings for Sitecore in IIS:

1. Ensure that Maximum Worker Processes for the Application Pool is set to 1 (under advanced settings)
2. Ensure that Load User Profile settings of the Application Pool is set to "true" (under advanced settings)
3. Ensure anonymous access is denied for:

   - /App_Config
   - /sitecore/admin
   - /sitecore/debug
   - /sitecore/webservice
4. Enable HTTP keep alive
5. Enable static content compression
6. On the CMS server, enable dynamic content compression
7. Disable execute permissions on the upload folder
8. Enable content expiration using HTTP response headers, especially for the /sitecore folder (optional)

For a multisite solution it is recommended to have just one application pool for all websites.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer from @Sitecore Climber, there's another thing you should be aware of:

- IIS and .NET requirements are different based on Sitecore version, and available depending on the Operational System you want to run.

For example

On [Sitecore 6.5](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/installation_guide_sc65-a4.pdf), the IIS version should be at least 5.1 with a .NET 3.5 SP1 in place.

On [Sitecore 7.5](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/installation_guide_sc75-a4.pdf), the IIS version should be at least 7.0 with .NET 4.5 in place